# Incorrect phasing of data from web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the values of a table from a website and compiling the data into a pandas dataframe. http://lbma.oblive.co.uk/table
However, I have several issues.

1. I can only select the default gold prices when I needed all five fields. i.e. Gold, Silver, GOFO/LIBOR, platinum and palladium.
2. The output of the data appears to be improperly phased. i.e. Its appears as a single array rather than the proper rows and columns as in the website.

Below is the rather simple code I attempted for web scraping but it is rather inadequate for the work. Hope you guys can help.

```
#Import packages
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Define url and output data
url = "http://lbma.oblive.co.uk/table"
data = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
0     Timestamp:2018-03-12 10:31:00 +0000      US...
```

Comment: `read_html` returns a list of DataFrames, is `pd.DataFrame(data)` really correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By selecting a metal type from the HTML option menu, the full url can be achieved:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import urllib
import pandas as pd
metals = map(lambda x:str(x).lower(), [i.text for i in soup(str(urllib.urlopen('http://lbma.oblive.co.uk/table?metal=silver&year=2018&type=daily').read()), 'lxml').find_all('option')])[:5]
dataframes = []
for metal in metals:
  table_results = [i.text for i in soup(str(urllib.urlopen('http://lbma.oblive.co.uk/table?metal={}&year=2018&type=daily'.format(metal)).read()), 'lxml').find_all('td')]
  new_table_data = {metal:[dict(zip(['timestamp', 'USD', 'GBP', 'EUR'], table_results[i:i+4])) for i in range(0, len(table_results), 4)]}
  dataframes.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_table_results,orient='index').transpose())
```